# Plague Inc. full version

Tags: plague-inc

I am under the impression that the free version will be upgraded to full version by completing all viruses in all difficulties. Am I right or is full version purchase only?

Comment: I'm quite sure you can't just get the game for free by essentially completing the demo. That's probably a nice urban legend, but not more than that. :)

Comment: Also you can't really complete the game in all difficulties. If you see someone that finished on Mega Brutal on mobile versions, call them hackers.

Answer (score 5):

Although you can't get the full game by that, but in the **paid** mobile version, DLCs are only virus unlock DLCs, you can just play and unlock them.

As you can see in the pictures, I unlocked them all without purchasing. And the game doesn't let me buy the DLCs anymore as I already unlocked them all (this isn't the steam version, this is the windows 8/10 universal app, I own both, I finished both)
[image: screenshot]
[image: screenshot 2]
[image: screenshot 3]